# WPF listbox force Rebinds after few scroll on it

Tags: wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a listbox that binds to a collection that implements InotifyPropertyChanged in two way binding mode. After few scroll on the listbox, The listbox loses binding with the current  collection and rebinds automatically with a new instance.

Comment: could you provide some code to test?

Comment: Can you show us the error message you get? I assume what you saw was the output window dispaying binding errors while you scroll. That is normal when using ListBox since ListBox supports virtualization by default. The ListBox doesn't lose connection to your collection.

Comment: I am sorry for replying late...Posting the code might be over too complex..but I am still finding a work around o unit test so that I can post.  VirtualizingStackPanel.ISvirtualising has been set to false. While I find a way to provide a code to unit test, I will try to explain in plain english.  I have two instances of a dataclass which contain  100 and 150 items repectively for ClassA and CLAssB.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that has contributed... Finally got a solution . Downloaded WPFINspector available @ codeplex and looked into my application  logical and visual tree. Finally found that a point of moving from one page to the other  another instance of the existing windows is being created... Thanks so much.